# Not able to connect to windows server 2012 after firewall is turned on

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-firewall, psexec

I am have Windows Server 2012 hosted with Datasoft. I was able to access the server using RDP until yesterday but mistakenly I have turned on the firewall with default settings. Since then i am not able to connect to server. I tried PSEXEC tools but its also not working and giving me an error.

[image: Error with PSEXEC]

Please suggest what to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. Conect from host in same subnet. Most likely to be able to connect from same subnet - depends on which profile is applied to the network.
2. KVM acces to server if possible.
3. Tech support help.

Comment: It is important to know the network mask, which your server settings. It can not be correct, but the firewall behavior will depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Services control panel to connect to the server & disabling the Firewall service from there? Open the Services control panel from Administrative tools & then from the Action menu select "Connect to another computer".

Failing that you can try the SC command from a command prompt. SC /? will give you a comprehensive list of commands available.

If that doesn't work, you could using remote WMI calls. This Powershell script will help you achieve that.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/212e68f0-5279-4499-8e9e-6aa1807719c0

Good luck